# How to create a series of lines perpendicular to a polyline

Tags: c#, wpf, polyline

After the user draws a polyline I need to create a series of perpendicular lines somewhat like this:

[image]

Looking at the points of a polyline in the debugger I notice that they're not contiguous. I can fix that by 'drawing' lines between the points and saving all points along the line. What would be the method for creating equal length perpendicular lines?

Comment: Please, add the code that draws it.

Comment: For each joint in the polyline, I guess I'd split the difference between the slopes of the two line segments that join there. At the ends, it's just perpendicular.

Comment: Right. I can't find an algorithm for drawing an equidistant perpendicular line.

Comment: Do you think you might be able to find a formula for the slope of a line bisecting the angle between two other lines? Or sit down with a pencil and a piece of graph paper and figure it out for yourself in ten minutes? Well, it'd probably take me half an hour, but I don't math good.

Comment: Thanks! That's really good advice. I hadn't thought of doing that.